# How to Store Multi Select Box in php?

Tags: php, mysql, select, multidimensional-array

am having select box with multiple options, like `option1,option2,option3,option4,option5`.Now i want to select more than one option.

---

For Example: `Select option1,option5,option3`.and click submit.after submitting the select box need to show the selected items.

---

in which format to be stored in mysql and what's the exact coding to do that?please help me to get rid of this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/03/20/492/

Answer (score 4):

You could serialize the data in and out.

Use name[] as your  name which results in an array in PHP.

```
$_POST['name'];
serialize($name);
//now insert into DB
```

Do the opposite to retrieve:

```
unserialize($name);
```

But to be honest you are better off looking at more granular methods of storing the data, rather than trying to stuff it all into one field in a database. You could take the array and loop through it storing each choice in a separate row or field.

```
foreach($name as $value){
//insert $value into db
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use implode

$var = implode ( "|", $_POST['selectname']);